# Laravel Query relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to determine the database relationship , for the following tables:

```
posts
======
id 
type_id
title 
content


posts_type
==========
id 
type_name
```

Where `type_id` and `posts_type` (id) is the same , where each post ganna have ONLY one type,
how do I define this in Laravel is it one to one relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `One-To-Many` relationship, for example:

Model `PostType`:

```
class PostType extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts_type';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'type_id', 'id');
    }

}

// Get PostType (whereId=1) with all related posts
$postType = PostType::with('posts')->find(1);
```

Model `Post`:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts'; // Optional

    public function postType()
    {
        return $this->belongs('PostType', 'type_id', 'id');
    }

}

// Get Post (whereId=1) with it's related PostType
$post = Post::with('postType')->find(1);
```

Comment: Yes, both are different models.

Comment: but I want to make sure than every post has only ONE type_id when you say hasMany isnt that means each post has many types??

Comment: No, each `Post` belongs to only one `PostType` but each `PostType` can have many `Post`.